# What is wrong with my Method.invoke call?

Tags: java, exception, reflection, java-8, invocation

I just created the following minimalistic testcase:

```
package testcase;

public class Main
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Throwable
    {
        if ( args.length == 0 )
            Main.class.getMethod( "main", String[].class ).invoke( null, new String[] { "test" } );
    }

}
```

It should just run, with no output and no exception. The `main` method should be calling itself using reflection. However I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at testcase.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

And I cannot figure out, why...

Comment: When you compile this you get a warning from the compiler which gives you a hint about what's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    if (args.length == 0)
        Main.class.getMethod("main", String[].class)
                  .invoke(null, new Object[] {new String[] { "test" }});
}
```

The problem is that `invoke` has vararg parameter which could be either array or plain list of objects and Java arrays are covariant. So `.invoke(null, new String[] { "test" })` is interpreted by compiler in the same way as `.invoke(null, new Object[] { "test" })`. You should have compiler warning about this ambiguity.

Comment: using `invoke(null, (Object) (new String[] { "test" }))` should work too, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Cast `new String[] { "test" }` in a `new Object[] {}`.