# Why NativeMethodAccessorImpl declare InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, exception, invocationtargetexception, native-methods

[NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke method](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java) declare it can throws  `IllegalArgumentException` or `InvocationTargetException`

> ```
> public Object invoke(Object obj, Object[] args)
>     throws IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
> {
>     // We can't inflate methods belonging to vm-anonymous classes because
>     // that kind of class can't be referred to by name, hence can't be
>     // found from the generated bytecode.
>     if (++numInvocations > ReflectionFactory.inflationThreshold()
>             && !ReflectUtil.isVMAnonymousClass(method.getDeclaringClass())) {
>         MethodAccessorImpl acc = (MethodAccessorImpl)
>             new MethodAccessorGenerator().
>                 generateMethod(method.getDeclaringClass(),
>                                method.getName(),
>                                method.getParameterTypes(),
>                                method.getReturnType(),
>                                method.getExceptionTypes(),
>                                method.getModifiers());
>         parent.setDelegate(acc);
>     }
>     return invoke0(method, obj, args);
> }
> private static native Object invoke0(Method m, Object obj, Object[] args);
> ```

Native method [throws IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125950/what-is-wrong-with-my-method-invoke-call) in some cases, e.g.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ```

But I don't see any option for throwing `InvocationTargetException` **checked exception**

Can `InvocationTargetException` be thrown by native method `invoke0` (which doesn't declare exceptions)?

Or is `InvocationTargetException` remains because of method signature backward/future compatibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[invoke0](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/loading-resources-files-in-java-11/28704) can throw `InvocationTargetException`:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

For example when FXML resource file was not found.